# Basics of Haml-Coffee for Backbone tempting

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, haml

I'm looking into Haml-Coffee and am a little confused about how to get it working. The github's information didn't seem very clear. Can anyone layout a basic use of it with Backbone for tempting.

Comment: Stack Overflow is more about getting answers to specific questions; if you're looking for a tutorial about a particular technology you'll probably have better luck elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your views as `window.HAML['template name here']` by default. (you can use `-n exports.JST` to have `exports.JST`). Starting from here, you have a function like any other templating engine :-).